# Unable to access object inside json file

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "epapconfig": {
        "suffix": "Enter Choice: ",
        "Display":{
            "suffix": "Press return to continue..."   
        },
        "Security":{
            "suffix": "Enter Choice: ",
            "Timeout":{
                "suffix": "Enter Choice: ",
                "Display" : {
                    "suffix" : "Press return to continue..."
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "epapdev": {
        "suffix": "]$ "
    },
    "su": {
        "suffix": "Password: "
    },
    "root": {
        "suffix": "]# "
    }
    
}
```

I am importing above json file as 'json_map' in python. Now I am able to access json_map['epapconfig']. but I am unable to access json_map['epapconfig']['Display']. . It is giving error as "'int' object is not subscriptable" . Any help will be appreciated

I want to access 'suffix' of 'Display'

Comment: It works for me. Can you provide also your script/code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your result; the JSON is well-formed, and after being parsed should be able to support `json_map['epapconfig']['Display']` without an error. Please post your exact code how you are "importing above json file".

Comment: Could you include the part of your code that is relevant to this error, and maybe try printing `json_map['epapconfig']` to check what the value of that is.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
dict = {
    "epapconfig": {
        "suffix": "Enter Choice: ",
        "Display": {
            "suffix": "Press return to continue..."
        },
        "Security": {
            "suffix": "Enter Choice: ",
            "Timeout": {
                "suffix": "Enter Choice: ",
                "Display": {
                    "suffix": "Press return to continue..."
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "epapdev": {
        "suffix": "]$ "
    },
    "su": {
        "suffix": "Password: "
    },
    "root": {
        "suffix": "]# "
    }

}

r=json.dumps(dict)

data = json.loads(r)

print(data['epapconfig']['Display']['suffix'])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks